# Vue CLI white page on production server

Tags: vue.js

I installed vue with webpack and router.

```
vue init webpack vue-project
```

Then, I installed npm and run application in dev mode on my local server

```
npm install
npm run dev
```

It worked perfect. However, on production server i get a white screen. After deploying my project I run

```
npm run build
```

I get white page. After looking through source codes, I didn't see any js into html.

```
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
```

I use Ubuntu and Nginx. Everything configured correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After breaking my head, I found a solution. Changing root directory to `dist` from nginx, solved this problem.

```
root   /var/www/vue-project/dist;
```